# Convert an array of image physical paths on server to array of urls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web Api to return a list of URLs to a client application. Since the Image files get created on the server, when a request comes in I need to respond with a list of the Image path URLs. Right now, I'm using the code below to accomplish this but it's returning physical paths rather than URLs.

```
string[] imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(outputImgPath,"*.png");
response.Images = new List<string>(imagePaths);
```

How could I go about returning the actual urls of the image on the server? I figure I could loop through all the files in the directory and convert them but I'm not sure how to go about that in a performant way.

Comment: Unless you have millions of paths then performance shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve all file name from directory and add them with web URL

```
string[] imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(outputImgPath,"*.png");
imagePaths.Select(x => string.Format("http://DOMAIN/Path/{0}" , Path.GetFileName(x)))
```

Comment: wouldn't the `x` in this case contain the server path still and just append it to the `http://DOMAIN/path/`  ?

Comment: Yes it is, you can use Path APIs to get filename